# Default states missing when state and country picklists are enabled

Tags: administration, metadata, picklist

I've had the "state and country picklist" feature enabled in a production org today. The documentation says:

> In this beta release, 239 countries are provided by default, as well as the states and provinces of the US, Canada, Australia, Brazil, China, India, Ireland, Italy, and Mexico.

But in the "Configure states and countries" page, when I click "Edit" on the "United States" entry I see no states, just the ability to add them one by one which is not how I want to spend the rest of my day...

I've opened a case on this but based on past experience it will take several days before it gets to someone who knows what is going on.

Has anyone recently turned on this feature and either got the states or not got the states? Am I missing something about how this feature is meant to work?'

**PS** Its a Force.com Enterprise edition org on na9.

Comment: What edition is your org?

Comment: I ask because it could be related to known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyCTAA0

Comment: And no, you're not missing anything. It sounds like a bug.

Comment: I've added the edition information to the question; given that the edition and symptoms don't match my problem is probably something different.

Comment: I agree, it's not that issue, then. I'm really sorry this is happening. One thing you could try is to take a look at the Address.Settings data using the Metadata API. That would let you see whether the states are present in the backend and it's a UI bug, or whether the states didn't load on default. You could also use the MD API to load the states en masse, as a workaround.

Comment: Good suggestions. For now I'm going to keep escalating the case to get sf support to take responsibility for what may be a goof on their part; but if I get desperate I guess programmatically creating the states is the way to go.

Comment: AddressTools is an application on the AppExchange that not only includes a Country picklist but also a State picklist with more than 3000 States worldwide, compared to only the USA and Canada as supported by Salesforce. Additionally it allows manual state input for Countries where the State picklist is unavailable, ensuring you can have every value you need on the picklist! Furthermore AddressTools includes a vast array of other features, including automatic timezone and time offset population, City State & Country auto-completion when a US ZIP code is entered, scheduled and interactive addres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed by salesforce support:

"It looks like something went wrong when enabling the feature for that Organization in particular, it was fixed with a script on your organization."